# Import flutter android project to iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm working on the Flutter Android project which is 90% complete, and I want this app to be usable for iOS. Is it possible that I can import this app to iOS without having to start over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand about Flutter, as long as you set up your Flutter project correctly it should work on both without issue.

Flutter is one of the most popular cross platform languages out there alongside React.
https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/02/21/why-flutter-is-the-most-popular-cross-platform-mobile-sdk/

If you were concerned about it not working on IOS because you are working on Android Studio, I think it still works, but you can always move your code to VS Code.

Comment: So do you mean that my project can run both android and iOS operation? @Jared

Comment: Yes it should be able to run on both Android and iOS operation. Flutter is designed to support mobile apps that run on both Android and iOS, as well as interactive apps that you want to run on your web pages or on the desktop.

Comment: That is great, thank you for the answer.

Comment: No problem. I have used this site a lot for my Flutter questions, so I suggest you do as well. If you are satisfied with this answer (or any answer to your questions in the future) you can hit the check mark on my answer accepting it as the correct answer to your problem.